# Pandas DataFrames Lists

Tags: python, dataframe

So I created a new column in my dataframe using a list. Now every entry has the ‘[ ]’ squared parentheses around the text. How do I remove them? Please help! It seems easy but I’m not getting there. Code used:

df.insert(1, ‘Email’, emails_list, True)

Now all the data in the Email column is in [square brackets]. I want to remove those parentheses.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have lists as values to each row in the column 'Email'. You can try the below code to take the first element of the list, and replace the original list with it.

```
df['Email'] = df['Email'].map(lambda x: x[0] if len(x)> 0 else '')
```

The above code takes each cell value of the column, and checks if it of non zero length. If it has non-zero length, then it replaces the list in the cell, with the first element of the list. Otherwise, it just replaces it with an empty string.

This should help. If the error persists, please check the type and shape of 'emails_list'